# photoshop saving image without white background

Tags: image, background, photoshop

i can't remove the white background when saving as png or jpeg.
tried everything what suggested me on the web, but still get the diminsions i set up as whitebackground.
How can i save image without the background?
see image below for settings.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQwJc.png)

Comment: You will have better luck with this question on the [Graphic Design Stack Exchange](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/). That said, if by "saving an image wihtout the background" you mean having a transparent background, that is impossible with JPEGs as that file fomrat does not support transparency. For PNGs, an online search for `Photoshop PNG transparent background` yields a whole bunch of tutorials

Comment: Tried what they suggested me, either it doesn't work because the dimensions i set up when i save the image as png just becomes white background or the tutorials are outdated.. some options i cn't find them in photoshop cc 2019(like 'save for web'), thanks gonna try to ask in graphic design stack exchange

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove all the white from the picture, better go to color range and sample white. layer via cut  and delete the layer. and save it in png as @cybernatic.nomad said, supports transparency.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have created your image on a new layer and delete (or hide) the first white layer. I just created a simple text on a new layer with a transparent background and then loaded the image back into Photoshop to confirm that it works properly. As per previous comment I use .png format to preserve transparency.

[image: Create File]

[image: Add new layer, hide white layer]

[image: Save as png]

[image: Open saved file into Photoshop to confirm transparency]